# Override web config setting from root config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have directory say Account in my Application.It contains web.config in it 
Also I have web config file present inside the root of an Application.

Now i have common configuration inside both config file

My requirement is that i got page inside Account directory which by default takes 
config setting from web config present in Account folder
I want it to use configuration from ROOT config file and not from folder.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file in your specific directory (Account) and you will take the configuration of your root
(It's inheritance of your config file)

Note : The top level is your machine.config

Another note : you can delete just specific section and not all file